# Different behaviour between inline and non-inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to build a timer. Please compare the two situations (the first one works, not the second):

- inline javascript http://jsfiddle.net/x7xhA/
- non-inline javascript http://jsfiddle.net/x7xhA/1/

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a commonly encountered problem with users of jsFiddle's 'JavaScript section'. You see, the code that's put into the 'JavaScript section' is wrapped within a function used as a `load` handler, so in your second example, the real output result is this:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  var seconds = 0;

function timedCount() {
    $("#txt").val(seconds);
    seconds += 1;
    setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}
  });
  //]]> 
  </script>
```

Now, `timedCount` isn't a global function anymore, as it's available in the scope of the `load` handler only, and when you use `setTimeout` with a string of code, this gets evaluated from the global scope.

Ways to fix this include:

**change the `setTimeout` call to `setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);`**

What this does, is passes the actual function object to `setTimeout`. Rather than evaluate the string of code, from global scope, each time, this essentially preserves the ability to call the function as scope doesn't matter anymore - you're handing the function to `setTimeout`.

```
  var seconds = 0;

function timedCount() {
    $("#txt").val(seconds);
    seconds += 1;
    setTimeout(timedCount,1000);
}
```

**make `timedCount` a global function using `timedCount = function() { ... };`**

This merely makes `timedCount` a global, so that when `setTimeout` tries to evaluate `timedCount();` from the global scope, it succeeds as there is a `timedCount` function in the global scope.

```
  var seconds = 0;

timedCount = function() {
    $("#txt").val(seconds);
    seconds += 1;
    setTimeout("timedCount();",1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second one wraps the `timedCount` function in jQuery `ready` function, hence is not available in global scope.

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/x7xhA/2/

Comment: Didn't know you're looking for a detailed explanation!